# c++ Getting a portion of a file

Tags: c++, save, loading

How can I skip parts of a file, then `ifstream` until a certain character is reached?

For example, in a text file, this is written:

```
'SaveNameExample'
variableExample = 5;
```

How would I get only the SaveNameExample without the `'`s , store that as a `std::string` variable, and then only get the 5 from the next line, to save as an `int` variable?

Comment: Read the whole line into a string and parse it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines should work:

```
string s = "";
char c = '';
int i = 0;

while(getline(fstream_name, temp)){
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++){
        if(temp[i] != "'")
            s += temp[i];
        if(temp[i] >= x || temp[i] <= y) //Where x and y are ascii values for 0 and 9, respectively
            c = temp[i];
    }
}

i = atoi(c);
```

This will only work in certain situations, but you should be able to manipulate it to fit what you are trying to do.